# C# mongoDB driver database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So i just got into programming and into C# & noSQL databases. 
I'm currently working on a small program, that shows the data of a `MongoDB` database on an `ASP.NET` webapplication. Im stuck with connecting to my local database.

The data needs to be stored in lblMotherboard:
This is my code.
builder.aspx:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMotherboard" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

builder.aspx.cs:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

    public void showMobos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var name = "";
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        MongoServer server = mongoClient.GetServer(); 
        MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");

        MongoCollection<Post> mobos = database.GetCollection<Post>("moederborden");
        foreach (Post parts in mobos.FindAll())
        {
            name = name + " " + parts.Aanbieder + " " + parts.ProductNaam; 
        }
        lblMotherboard.Text = name; 
    }
```

`showMobos_Click` starts when a button is clicked. It doesn't print any data. What is going wrong?

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a287ef0d0a7f888510d14e"),
    "Aanbieder" : "Coolblue",
    "Productlink" : "http://computerstore.nl/product/470130/category-208983/asrock-z97-extreme6.html",
    "Productnaam" : "Asus H97-Pro Gamer",
    "Prijs" : "129,-",
    "Socket" : "1150"
}
```

Post.class:

```
public class Post
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public String Aanbieder { get; set; }
    public String Productlink { get; set; }
    public String Productnaam { get; set; }
    public decimal Prijs { get; set; } 
    public int Socket { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception? or mobos is empty?

Comment: When i load up the application and click inspect element it says in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Mobos isn't empty.

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with mongo, your usage of mongo driver is ok

Comment: So what could be the problem then ?

Comment: debug your code, do you enter your showMobos_Click method? try a simple insert into mobos collection and see if you get a 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException' or not.

Comment: I found the problem, it was not running my method. Now, i ran into a FileformatException. It is because, in my Post class, I have the element "prijs" (price) as a decimal, but some prices in my database have a price like this 200,-. So I guess that's the problem now. Is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: post a sample document and the Post class in your question

Comment: Why the Prijs looks like "129,-", it not a number

Comment: That's because it's data i crawled from several websites, and prices that are €129,00 are written as 129,-. Other documents have the price of, for example: 127,50. Prijs = price

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67941/discussion-between-disposer-and-henktenk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `Prijs` to a number

Run this in mongo console:

```
db.moederborden.find().forEach(function(doc)
{
    var price = doc.Prijs.replace(',', ''); // it may be vary for your other document
    price = price.replace('-', '');    
    doc.Prijs = Number(price);

    db.moederborden.update({_id : doc._id} , doc);
})
```